# Solve: $\sqrt{x-\frac1x}-\sqrt{1-\frac1x}=1-\frac1x$ for $ x\neq0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, radicals

$$\sqrt{x-\frac{1}{x}}-\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x}}{=1-\frac{1}{x}}, x\neq0$$
So my idea is that I moved the second sqrt to the RHS and left the first on the LHS. I then squared everything and ended up with $\frac{x^2-1}{x}=2-\frac{3}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}$. I don't know what to do next? Can somebody give a hint?

Comment: $x=1$ is a solution.

Comment: @vadim123 I am aware, what help does that give me? I want to solve it not just guess it.

Comment: It helps because you can factor $(x-1)$ out, as in rbird's solution.

Comment: Yes but my intention was to see how to do it. Sometimes the equation will be harder and I won't be able to guess it that easily.

Comment: i think your and the other Solutions are wrong, by squaring one times one square root on the right Hand side must remain

Comment: correct your Solutions please!

Comment: no if i do so like you then i have $$x-\frac{1}{x}=1-\frac{1}{x}+2(1-\frac{1}{x})\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x}}+1-\frac{1}{x}$$ after the formula $$(a+b)^2=a^2+b^2+2ab$$ note this for the future!

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner You are right. This was a stupid mistake.

Comment: yes it was and note this for the future!

Comment: and think about the Points you have given for a wrong solution!

Answer (score 4):

Multiply everything by $x^2$:
$$x^3-x=2x^2-3x+1$$
Rearrange:
$$x^3-2x^2+2x-1=0.$$
Note that $x-1$ is a factor:
$$(x-1)(x^2-x+1)=0$$
Now hopefully you can solve it.

Comment: Well that was easier than I thought. Didn't see that I can factorize it like that.  Thanks!

Comment: this is also wrong, you must square two times!

Answer (score 2):

Note that $x=1$ is a solution. Else, let $A = \sqrt{x-\frac{1}{x}}$ and $B = \sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x}}$

then $A-B = \frac{x-1}{x}$ and $A^2-B^2 = x-1$, then dividing we get $A+B = x$

Adding we get $2\sqrt{x-\frac{1}{x}} = 1+x - \frac{1}{x}$ or $2A = 1+A^2 \Rightarrow A=1$ or $x^2-x+1 = 0$

Answer (score 1):

squaring two times and foctorizing we get
$$-\frac{(x-1)^2 \left(x^2-x-1\right)^2}{x^4}=0$$
if we do so 
we get
$$x-\frac{1}{x}=(1-\frac{1}{x})^2+1-\frac{1}{x}+2(1-\frac{1}{x})\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x}}$$
the square root is missing !!
and you must square again!!!!!!!

Answer (score 0):

The domain gives $-1\leq x<0$ or $x\geq1$.

1. $-1\leq x<0$.

We obtain:
$$\sqrt{\frac{(1-x)(x+1)}{-x}}=\frac{\left(\sqrt{1-x}\right)^2}{x}+\sqrt{\frac{1-x}{-x}}$$ or
$$\sqrt{\frac{x+1}{-x}}=\frac{\sqrt{1-x}}{x}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{-x}}$$ or
$$-\sqrt{-x(x+1)}=\sqrt{1-x}-\sqrt{-x}$$ or
$$\sqrt{-x}=\sqrt{1-x}+\sqrt{-x(1+x)}$$ or
$$-x=1-x-x-x^2+2\sqrt{x(x^2-1)}$$ or
$$x^2+x-1=2\sqrt{x(x^2-1)},$$ which is impossible because $x^2+x-1<0$ for $-1\leq x<0.$

2. $x\geq1$.

We obtain:
$$\sqrt{\frac{(x-1)(x+1)}{x}}=\frac{x-1}{x}+\sqrt{\frac{x-1}{x}},$$ which gives
$$x=1$$ or
$$\sqrt{\frac{x+1}{x}}=\frac{\sqrt{x-1}}{x}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{x}},$$ which is
$$\sqrt{(x+1)x}=\sqrt{x-1}+\sqrt{x}$$ or
$$x^2+x=2x-1+2\sqrt{(x-1)x}$$ or
$$x^2-x-2\sqrt{(x-1)x}+1=0$$ or
$$\left(\sqrt{x^2-x}-1\right)^2=0$$ or
$$x^2-x-1=0,$$ which gives
$$x=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$$ and we got the answer:
$$\left\{1,\frac{1+\sqrt5}{2}\right\}$$